# Lebesgue Integral of Characteristic function.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Let $A_n = [1-n,n-1]$.  Define $$\chi_{\mathbb{R} \setminus A_n} := \begin{cases}
1 \qquad x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus A_n \\
0 \qquad \text{ else }
\end{cases}$$

Is it true that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \chi_{\mathbb{R} \setminus A_n} \, d \mu = \infty$$ yet $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \lim_{n \to \infty} \chi_{\mathbb{R} \setminus A_n} = 0?$$

In both cases, this is  a Lebesgue Integral. Think of this function as the line $y=1$ 'falling' to $0$.

Comment: That's correct. Probably this is a counterexample to your other question that the $f_1 \in L_1$ condition is dropped.

Comment: @JohnMa Yes of course haha. This was my own example, and I wanted to know if it was correct without sharing the problem as to not have a correct solution handed to me.